# Can I use Unity remote with a Android emulator instead of Android phone?

Tags: unity-game-engine

*Unity Remote* is good app. It allows to connect with Unity while you are running your project in Play mode from the editor.

But what if I want to test game but I don't have an Android phone? Yes, it happens ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I have a great Android emulator: *Nox APP Player*

[image: screenshot]

The emulator doesn't have `USB`, so it just show me standsrt text `Connect device with a USB cable .....` bla bla bla ...Game in the Unity Editor is running...emulator doesn't display the game.

Can I somehow connect this emulator to unity using *Unity Remote*? Or using something else? How?

Comment: What is stopping you from using Unity Remote on the emulator? What happens when you try?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain He does not not have Android phone. It shouldn't work because Unity connects to it through USB port. Assuming  Unity Remote supports TCP/IP then this can be done.

Comment: @Programmer yes, he is using a android phone emulator. That still does not change the question, what goes wrong if you treated the emulator like a phone and tried it? I am 75% sure it is just using the ADB link to the android device, which the emulator should be exposing

Comment: If you just want to see what unity Remote looks like, you can use your iPad, iPhone, or any Android device.  But it is an absolute waste of your time: it's literally pointless.  (Regarding whether you could get it working on an emulator - it's an irrelevant waste of your time.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain emulator shows me standart text `Connect device with a  USB cable .....` bla bla bla ...and that's it.Game in the Unity Editor is running...emulator doesn't display the game. I do not know how can I emulate USB connection on emulator)) Should I do that? I don't know what to do at all. That is why I'm here - to know is it possible?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I took time to try this on all Android emualors that exist but none of then worked. I really don't think that is using the ADB command to work. It seems like it is using a raw USB connection because there are many features it has that is not available through ADB.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain @Programmer `AVD Manager.exe` from `sdk` allows to create android emulator....adb is launching... and I even can synchronize it with Unity.....it works......unfortunately these emulators don't allow to emulate touches, screen shake, like `Nox APP Player`...... that was the 2-nd reason is why I wrote about `Nox APP Player`.....synchronization with this app do not working(( despite the fact that the nox_adb is launching http://s019.radikal.ru/i629/1607/de/47782e9b419a.jpg

Comment: @Programmer standard Android emulators allow to do that....but they have not anought tools for game testing i.e. touch simulation

Comment: It is a mind-boggling waste of your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you still need the solution for this problem, but I think I should leave an solution for those who come later.

You can connect Nox with Unity via UnityRemote (I'm using Unity Remote 5) with the adb of Nox. Here the steps :

- Rename your adb.exe to other (i.e adb_origin.exe). It's normally located at SDK folder\platform-tools
- Go to Nox installation folder\bin, looking for nox_adb.exe, copy it to the location of your origin adb.exe
- Rename nox_adb.exe to adb.exe
- Open cmd and enter : adb.exe connect localhost:62001 and you will see "already connected to localhost:62001". If not, you can try replace localhost by 127.0.0.1
- Then apply steps 3 → 7 of @Alexey
- At the Resolution dropdown, you can choose Normal (default is Downsize) to have better image quality on Nox

Note that after all of this, you should restore the origin adb.exe for later use.
Here is my result picture :

[image: Successful pic, sorry I can't post it directly]

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: cheater :)  Finally I've had time to check this answer. Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Took from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/126192/81175</sub>

---

I was able to run Unity Remote 4 on standard Android emulator.

Final effect looks something like [image: Final effect]

Whole procedure:

1. Install Unity and open some Unity tutorial project (2D Roguelike tutorial in my case)
2. Install JDK, Android SDK and setup Android emulator using AVD Manager.
   My emulator config looks like this:[image: Emulator config]

**Important note:** CPU/ABI option seems to be one of most important ones(Intel x86 emulator didn't work for me)

3. Then install Unity Remote 4 from apk file to emulator using command: `adb.exe install path/to/apk` (Windows) or `adb install path/to/apk` (Linux/Mac).
4. Then in Edit → Preferences → External Tools — set paths to Android SDK and JDK
5. In Edit → Project Settings → Editor in section Unity Remote select: Any Android Device.
6. In File → Build Settings — add Your scenes and switch platform to Android.
7. Press PLAY in Unity while Android Emulator is running and Unity Remote 4 app is opened.

**Tip:** At first I needed to restart unity after all changes, because it wasn't starting game on emulator. Now it runs everytime.

---

However, it works for `AVD Manager` emulators. I've tried them too, before I asked the question, and they didn't work because of `CPU/ABI Intel x86` as @Axxxon said...now it works with `CPU - ARM armeabi`...

Unfortunately `NOX APP PLayer` doesn't connect. Maybe it because it's not have `CPU/ABI` settings. Or I just don't get how to launch this player with `Unity`.

It is said. Because `NOX APP` has touch simulating, screen shaking and other good stuff for checking game. AVD emulators doesn't have these things :'-( therefore they are useless for me.

But maybe this answer will help to someone.

Comment: No even kidding. I tried all those too and it didn't work. NOX APP PLayer,bluestack emulator and Microsoft Android Emulator failed. I just don't have time to do this experiment again. Congrats for getting it work for you.

Comment: oomph.....I tried  AVD Manager standart emulators. They work well, but absolutely useless for me.... NOX APP PLayer,bluestack emulator - didn't work, but they do need me.....it so sad.... I should buy Android, I guess %)

Comment: You should have android device already when developing for mobile devices. You can't release your game without testing it on a physical device. Go for it.

Comment: Can you clarify on step 3? How do you find the path to the apk, and what directory do I have to be in to run that command? Thanks

Comment: @obl you should download `UnityRemote.apk` (for example from here http://apk-dl.com/unity-remote-4/) . Then in step 3 - you should write a path where the file (UnityRemote.apk) is located (where it was downloaded), e.g. `c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe install "c:\Users\me\Desktop\Unity Remote_5.2.0.apk`.